# why it's not alerting my information from WeathermapAPI

Tags: javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var api="http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=dehradun,india&           APPID=ab399c2f90228bbdabc65d72b81a1b4d";

    $.getJSON(api,function(data){

        alert(data.coord.lat);

    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this piece of code:

```
var api="http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=dehradun,india&           APPID=ab399c2f90228bbdabc65d72b81a1b4d";
```

to:

```
var api="http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=dehradun,india&APPID=ab399c2f90228bbdabc65d72b81a1b4d";
```

Please add the jquery cdn to your html if you haven't added it. Try this piece of code:

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.0.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-RTQy8VOmNlT6b2PIRur37p6JEBZUE7o8wPgMvu18MC4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

    var api="http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=dehradun,india&APPID=ab399c2f90228bbdabc65d72b81a1b4d";

    $.getJSON(api,function(data){

       alert(data.coord.lat);

    });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is lot of spaces in the URL query strings. Remove the blank spaces before `APPID`

**Note:** To make the below code snippet to work, I used `https` in the API URL because StackOverflow uses `https` protocol.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    var api="https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=dehradun,india&APPID=ab399c2f90228bbdabc65d72b81a1b4d";;

    $.getJSON(api,function(data){

       alert(data.coord.lat);

    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```